# Pandas groupby discards columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

And once I run following code: `DF= DF.groupby('CIF').mean()` (and fill NaN with zeros)

I get following dataframe:

[image]

Why are two columns 'CYCLE' and 'BALANCE.GEL' disappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are mixed missing values, numeric and strings repr of numbers, so columns are [removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).

So try convert all columns without `CIF` to numbers and because `CIF` column is converted to index is possible aggregate by `mean` per index:

```
DF= DF.set_index('CIF').astype(float).mean(level=0)
```

If first solution failed then use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non numbers to `NaN`s:

```
DF= DF.set_index('CIF').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mean(level=0)
```

Comment: You are right, there was a single string entry among all the floating point, which resulted in this. Thank you